# [] brackets in sql server for injection

Tags: sql, sql-server

We use [ ] brackets as delimiters in our SQL query. This allows us to make use of special characters or reserved words to be used to create database name,etc.

I am trying to test if I can inject something malicious in the below query which is a simple create db but with [ ]

```
create database [x; Drop database ">>"] ;
```

But it seems that whatever is inside the delimiter is a character. Does it mean we can not have SQL injection if we use delimiters?

template:

```
create database [" + userProvidedString + "]
```

Comment: The main trick in SQL injection is terminating the opening delimiter. i.e. what do you think happens when you put this in? `dummydb] GO DROP DATABASE [goodbye] SELECT 1 as [test`

Comment: The correct way of sanitising the `userProvidedString` for object names is to use the `QUOTENAME` function

Comment: I would recommend that you parameterize this statement `DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(200) = 'CREATE DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(?); EXEC sp_executesql @sql`